# PriorityQueue Java не работает - не работает сортировка

Tags: java, data-structures

У меня почему-то не работает Priority Queue 
А именно - я задаю comparator и начинаю вставлять элементы - а они вставляются не по порядку :( 
Судя по гуглу - это я что-то намудрила, но как оно должно быть на деле - не ясно. 
Я вставляю элемент Cell  и прошу отсортировать по кол-ву элементов в массиве - но нет. 
Код вот:

```
PriorityQueue <Cell> que = new PriorityQueue<Cell>(domComp);
//list - коллекция Cells
que.addAll(list);
public static Comparator<Cell> domComp = new Comparator<Cell>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Cell c1, Cell c2) {
            return (c1.domain.size() - c2.domain.size());
        }
    };
```

Фото с результатами прилагаю

[image: Вот как это выглядит :(]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) - это [куча](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)), а потому она не гарантирует порядок при обходе, только порядок при извлечении элемента:

```
while (!que.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(que.poll());
}
```

Comment: Поняла. Ещё момент - она не обновляется сама, если значение элемента внутри поменялось?

Comment: Нет, куча перестраивается только при добавлении и удалении элементов.